# Successful predictions of MO software?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, reference-request

There have been many successful predictions of MO software. Is there a website or journal dedicated to recording them all?

Comment: No. There are far too many and it wouldn't really be very useful.

Comment: I'd expand bon's answer a bit. MO models are used to predict some particular behavior of a molecule rather that how the molecule would behave under all circumstances. So for example it is just too complicated as of yet to "seamlessly" model NMR, IR, UV-Vis, mass spec, boiling point, melting point, and chemical reactivity of a molecule in the solid, liquid and gas phases in a single MO model.

Comment: @MaxW is there a table associating which models describe certain phenomena - ideally under stated ranges of conditions?